# Animated transition on TabBarController?.selectedIndex change? (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

Is it possible to create a custom `tabBarController` class in swift to animate programmatic and interactive transitions between tabs?

Comment: Which kind of transitions do you have in mind?

Comment: Just like a normal sugue

Comment: I can't help much on iOS (just on OSX). It was just a question that came to mind when I reviewed your question. You need to wait for someone else to chip in.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this for transition animation on tabbar selecetion

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {

guard let fromView = selectedViewController?.view, let toView = viewController.view else {
    return false
}

UIView.transition(from: fromView, to: toView, duration: 0.3, options: [.transitionCrossDissolve], completion: nil)
return true }
```

for reference use this link

[How to animate Tab bar tab switch with a CrossDissolve slide transition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44346280/how-to-animate-tab-bar-tab-switch-with-a-crossdissolve-slide-transition)

Comment: This doesn't work when programatically calling .setSelectedIndex, however it does work when tapping tabs on the tab bar controller. Is there any way to improve your answer so that it will work for the method call mentioned?

Answer (score 1):

I just figured this out, and posted an answer on another thread (link below). It adds a method:

tabBarController.setSelectedWithIndex(1)

to get this done with an animation.

I hope it works for you!

Answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57116930/1993937