# ViewController slide animation

Tags: swift, facebook, animation, uiviewcontroller, tabbar

I want to create an animation like the **iOS app facebook at tabswitch**<sup>[1]</sup>. I have already tried to develop some kind of animation, the problem that occurs is that the old view controller becomes invisible directly on the switch, instead of fading out slowly while the new controller is sliding in fast.

I've found this SO question [How to animate Tab bar tab switch with a CrossDissolve slide transition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44346280/how-to-animate-tab-bar-tab-switch-with-a-crossdissolve-slide-transition) but the as correct marked solution does not really work for me (it is not a slide it is a fade transition). What I'd also like to get is the function to make slide left or right to switch the tabs. Like it was on a older version of facebook.

What I've got so far is this:

```
extension TabBarController: UITabBarControllerDelegate  {
    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
        guard let fromView = selectedViewController?.view,
              let toView = viewController.view else { return false }
        if fromView != toView {
            toView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: -90, y: 0)
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, delay: 0.0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
                toView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 0)
            })
        }; return true
    }
}
```

---

```
class TabBarController: UITabBarController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        delegate = self
    }
}
```

**How to fix this?**

---

<sup>[1]</sup>
I would very much like to add a gif from the Facebook app. The problem is that I don't want to censor the video and just reveal too much of my data. (Even if fb already has them). Also on youtube I didn't find a suitable recording. Please try it yourself in the fb app in iOS.

Comment: so why answer that you mentioned is not suitable for you?

Comment: Here's a gist that uses `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning `: https://gist.github.com/dsoike/caa34a2605306f28c3061efc4920ba13

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the following idea: https://samwize.com/2016/04/27/making-tab-bar-slide-when-selected/

Also, here's the code updated to Swift 4.1 and I also removed the force unwrappings:

```
import UIKit

class MyTabBarController: UITabBarController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        delegate = self
    }
}

extension MyTabBarController: UITabBarControllerDelegate  {
    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
        guard let tabViewControllers = tabBarController.viewControllers, let toIndex = tabViewControllers.index(of: viewController) else {
            return false
        }
        animateToTab(toIndex: toIndex)
        return true
    }

    func animateToTab(toIndex: Int) {
        guard let tabViewControllers = viewControllers,
            let selectedVC = selectedViewController else { return }

        guard let fromView = selectedVC.view,
            let toView = tabViewControllers[toIndex].view,
            let fromIndex = tabViewControllers.index(of: selectedVC),
            fromIndex != toIndex else { return }


        // Add the toView to the tab bar view
        fromView.superview?.addSubview(toView)

        // Position toView off screen (to the left/right of fromView)
        let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
        let scrollRight = toIndex > fromIndex
        let offset = (scrollRight ? screenWidth : -screenWidth)
        toView.center = CGPoint(x: fromView.center.x + offset, y: toView.center.y)

        // Disable interaction during animation
        view.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3,
                       delay: 0.0,
                       usingSpringWithDamping: 1,
                       initialSpringVelocity: 0,
                       options: .curveEaseOut,
                       animations: {
                        // Slide the views by -offset
                        fromView.center = CGPoint(x: fromView.center.x - offset, y: fromView.center.y)
                        toView.center = CGPoint(x: toView.center.x - offset, y: toView.center.y)

        }, completion: { finished in
            // Remove the old view from the tabbar view.
            fromView.removeFromSuperview()
            self.selectedIndex = toIndex
            self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        })
    }
}
```

So, you need to subclass UITabBarController and you also have to write the animation part, you can tweak the animation options (delay, duration, etc).

I hope it helps, cheers!

[image]

Comment: Sure, there you go.

Comment: Oh yeah, I was reading something else. Don't know if that's a good UI/UX from my point of view, you started this about a functionality that the Facebook app has, the slide gesture is not existent in the Facebook app. You should post a new question, you asked for the animation...

Comment: When the transition is happening, the topbar color of the controller changes and it causes annoying flash effect. How to solve it? check the video please https://drive.google.com/file/d/15mlR9NfV_1C8gwi-4vfpV4CxpXbG5BUm/view

Comment: @UtkuDalmaz can you post a sample of your code on github or somewhere? I can look into your issue if I can reproduce it.

Comment: I posted my code already. I was using your code but then I changed it to a similar code, here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62343102/tabbar-transition-animation-topbar-color-issue can you help me on this?

Answer (score 8):

I've never seen Facebook so I don't know what the animation is. But you can have *any* animation you like when a tab bar controller changes its tab (child view controller), *coherently* and without any hacks, using the built-in mechanism that Apple provides for adding custom animation to a transition between view controllers. It's called *custom transition animation*.

Apple first introduced this mechanism in 2013. Here's a link to their video about it: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2013/218/

I immediately adopted this in my apps, and I think it makes them look a lot spiffier. Here's a demo of a tab bar controller custom transition that I like:

[image]

The really cool thing is that once you've decided what animation you want, making the transition *interactive* (i.e. drive it with a gesture instead of a button click) is easy:

[image]

Now, you might be saying: Okay, but that's not quite the animation I had in mind. No problem! Once you've got the hang of the custom transition architecture, changing the animation to anything you like is easy. In this variant, I just commented out one line so that the "old" view controller doesn't slide away:

[image]

So let your imagination run wild! Adopt custom transition animations, the way that iOS intends.

Comment: Can you post some code too? I would really like to see how you implemented this custom transition.

Comment: For the code that generated those transitions, see https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch06p300customAnimation3b/ch19p620customAnimation1/AppDelegate.swift

Comment: Thank you @matt for this answer and the WWDC video link

Answer (score 2):

If you want something for pushViewController navigation, you can try this.

However, when switching between tabs on a TabBarController, this will not work. For that, I'd go with @mihai-erős 's solution

Change the Animation duration as per your liking, and assign this class to your navigation segues, for a Slide Animation.

```
class CustomPushSegue: UIStoryboardSegue {

    override func perform() {
        // first get the source and destination view controllers as UIviews so that they can placed in navigation stack

        let sourceVCView = self.source.view as UIView!
        let destinationVCView = self.destination.view as UIView!
        let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width

        //create the destination view's rectangular frame i.e starting at 0,0 and equal to screenwidth by screenheight
        destinationVCView?.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: screenWidth, y: 0)

        //the destinationview needs to be placed on top(aboveSubView) of source view in the app window stack before being accessed by nav stack
        // get the window and insert destination View
        let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow
        window?.insertSubview(destinationVCView!, aboveSubview: sourceVCView!)


        // the animation: first remove the source out of screen by moving it at the left side of it and at the same time place the destination to source's position
        // Animate the transition.
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: { () -> Void in
            sourceVCView?.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: -screenWidth,y: 0)
            destinationVCView?.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity

        }, completion: { (Finished) -> Void in
            self.source.present(self.destination, animated: false, completion: nil)
        }) 
    }
}
```