# Make a swipe from left edge to dismiss UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift

Example I have two `UIViewController` (I'll called A and B)

In A, when I click a button, I will show B with code:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"BController") as! BController
present(viewController, animated: true)
```

I don't use the navigate ViewController in Storyboard file.
So, does it have any solution to when Applicaion in B, I swipe the screen from left edge and B will dismiss.

You can imagine what I want in this image

[image]

Comment: _"I dont use Navigation Controller in my Project!!!"_ Why!!!

Comment: @RakeshaShastri cause my project is quite complex and it's big now, many storyboard and ViewController and I can't change this structure

Comment: How would you be changing the structure? All you need to do is add a navigation controller.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri I did it, it completely what I want, thanks. more details in my answer bellow

Comment: https://github.com/satishVekariya/DraggableViewController

Answer (score 1):

Add A Controller to a `NavigationController`
I make this by code:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"AController")
 let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController)
 navigationController.isNavigationBarHidden = true
 self.present(navigationController, animated: true)
```

then from A

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(bController, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to write an *interactive custom transition animation*. Doing so is complex but well documented in tutorials and examples.

Comment: For example see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51580236/341994 That is a tab bar controller not a dismiss of a presented controller, but the mechanics are exactly the same.

Comment: thanks, it will take more time to investigate. I noted and will read later.