# tabbar transition animation topbar color issue

Tags: swift, animation, uitabbarcontroller

I use this function to animate tabbar transition

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {

        guard let tabViewControllers = tabBarController.viewControllers, let toIndex = tabViewControllers.firstIndex(of: viewController) else {
            return false
        }
         animateToTab(toIndex: toIndex)   

        return true
      }

 func animateToTab(toIndex: Int) {
        guard let tabViewControllers = viewControllers,
            let selectedVC = selectedViewController else { return }



        guard let fromView = selectedVC.view,
            let toView = tabViewControllers[toIndex].view,
            let fromIndex = tabViewControllers.firstIndex(of: selectedVC),
            fromIndex != toIndex else { return }



        // Add the toView to the tab bar view
        fromView.superview?.addSubview(toView)

        // Position toView off screen (to the left/right of fromView)
        let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
        let scrollRight = toIndex > fromIndex
        let offset = (scrollRight ? screenWidth : -screenWidth)
        toView.center = CGPoint(x: fromView.center.x + offset, y: toView.center.y)

        // Disable interaction during animation
        view.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3,
                       delay: 0.0,
                       usingSpringWithDamping: 1,
                       initialSpringVelocity: 0,
                       options: .curveEaseOut,
                       animations: {
                        // Slide the views by -offset
                        fromView.center = CGPoint(x: fromView.center.x - offset, y: fromView.center.y)
                        toView.center = CGPoint(x: toView.center.x - offset, y: toView.center.y)

        }, completion: { finished in
            // Remove the old view from the tabbar view.
            fromView.removeFromSuperview()
            self.selectedIndex = toIndex
            self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        })
    }
```

When the transition is happening, the topbar color of the controller changes and it causes an annoying flash effect.

check the video, please

https://drive.google.com/file/d/15mlR9NfV_1C8gwi-4vfpV4CxpXbG5BUm/view

How can I prevent this?

Comment: What are you using as a topbar? Is it a navigationBar or something else? Is translucent property enabled or disabled?

Comment: @MihaiErős navigationbar with style is black and translucent

Comment: Disable translucent and try it out, let me know how it goes.

Comment: But for this project translucent looking is a must. Isn't there any way to make it work well without disabling translucent?

Comment: Hmm, so you want a black navigation bar with that kind of alpha, right? But without the glitch that comes with translucent.

Comment: I am sure there should be a way to code that effect working well with translucent

Comment: Basically you would need an IBOutlet for your navigationBar if there's no navigationController and you hide it when viewWillDisappear and show it when viewWillAppear. Check this out: https://github.com/MihaiEros/StackOverflow_-62343102

Comment: But I think you should use the animateAlongsideTransition:completion: or animateAlongsideTransitionInView:animation:completion: API, rather than relying on the implicit animations of viewWillAppear: and viewWillDisappear:.

Comment: @MihaiErős I also tried with that but got the same result https://gist.github.com/dsoike/caa34a2605306f28c3061efc4920ba13

Comment: There's something else wrong in your code, here, I can show you that my solution works: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1emoEzGgpKWvZGT_iu9sQZz5iTENFlSGr/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I fixed it by disabling translucent navigation bar