# TabView switching between tabs animated for SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, tabview

I have a `TabView` and I want to do animated switching between pages, like this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54774397/5376525

[image: animated switch between tabs]

Is it possible for SwiftUI?

Answer (score -1):

I actually just implemented this using SwiftUI.  Here's what I did:

1) Create a SwiftUI view that conforms to `UIViewControllerRepresentable.` I used the init method to provide it an array of SwiftUI views of type `AnyView.` There is some work to do in the `makeUIViewController` and the `updateUIViewController` methods so we'll come back to that.

I created a `typealias` to pass a tuple of Views, their Image Name (assuming you're using system images) and the View name.  It looks like this:

`typealias TabBarItemView = (ViewName: String, ImageName: String, TargetView: AnyView)`

2) You'll need to create a class that conforms to the `UITabBarControllerDelegate.` Within that delegate, you can override the `tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, animationControllerForTransitionFrom fromVC: UIViewController, to toVC: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` method.

Part of this requires you to create another class, one that conforms to `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning.` This class requires you to implement two functions: `transitionDuration(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> TimeInterval` which just needs you to specify how long you want the animation to last.

The second function is `animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning)` which requires you to do some heavier lifting.  Within this function, you'll need to design the animation that moves the views.  Essentially, you should be applying a `CGAffineTransform` that moves the view from off screen (imagine a stage to the left or right of the screen) onto the screen while moving the other view in the same direction off-screen.  At the end of the function, you can animate your transforms using something like:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: animationDuration, animations: moveViewsClosure, completion: cleanUpClosure)
```

where `animationDuration` specifies how long this will take, `moveViewsClosure` is applying the transforms, and `cleanUpClosure` is actually replacing the views with one-another.

Once you have the class conforming to `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` you should be able to return it as the output of the `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` function.

3) Now that you have your delegate and animation classes created, you can assign the delegate to a `UITabViewController` within the SwiftUI view we started in.  At the top of the struct, I created a variable of type `UITabViewController` and used the default initializer.  Within the `init` function, you should set the delegate to an instance of the delegate class we created above.

4) Now we can implement the `makeUIViewController` and the `updateUIViewController` functions.  Within `makeUIViewController` you'll need to load the array of views using the `UIHostingController` to enable your SwiftUI views to sit in the UIKit view controller.  Once you have all your views loaded, you can return the `UITabViewController` from the top.  Within the `updateUIViewController`, you will likely need to reset the delegate to the view controller.  Because SwiftUI is using structs, it is not uncommon for your view to get recreated as it is updated; I have found it will lose the reference to the delegate as a result and this was how I solved it.

I realize I could have provided all of my code, but it's fairly lengthy and I think you'll have an easier time troubleshooting it if you understand the process.